# How to begin a veins simulation at t > 0

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am working on veins simulation with LuST scenario. My goal is to choose a time period and begin my veins simulation at a certain moment, e.g. 6:00, of LuST. In SUMO, parameter "begin" can be modified so it's easy to set traffic flow. So I think it might work to begin veins simulation at time t > 0 without simulating before t. However, OMNeT++ kernel seems only able to run from 0s.

So my question is: how to begin veins simulation directly at time t > 0? If not, can I reset the time of SUMO scenario (which is, e.g., 6*3600) to 0s so as to cooperate with OMNeT++ and enable normal veins simulation? Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I find now is to **edit the parameter firstStepAt in TraCIScenarioManager.ned**. To be specific, add

```
*.manager.firstStepAt = 21600s
```

in omnetpp.ini.

This is a parameter to specify when to start synchronizing with TraCI and the default value is -1 (immediately after connecting to TraCI). After changing it to 21600s / 6:00, veins will connect to SUMO at 0s but not synchronize with SUMO until 6:00. Therefore, I only need to wait for sumo to run for 21600s, which is only a few seconds in reality.

Sorry for asking a immature question but I expect my experience can be helpful.

Comment: This is exactly how it is supposed to be done. Nice work in figuring that out by yourself and posting it as an answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation :)